# How to exit from PDFkit in swift

Tags: swift, pdf, pdfkit

I 'm working in a PDF display app by swift, the problem is when I open a pdf file, there is no back button.
I'm use PDFkit and it's not connected with storyboard.

```
    private func resourceUrl(forFileName fileName: String) -> URL? {
        if let resourceUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "pdf") {
           return resourceUrl
        }
        return nil
    }
    private func createPdfDocument(forFileName fileName: String) -> PDFDocument? {
        if let resourceUrl = self.resourceUrl(forFileName: fileName) {
            return PDFDocument(url: resourceUrl)
        }
        return nil
    }
    private func createPdfView(withFrame frame: CGRect) -> PDFView {
        let pdfView = PDFView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        pdfView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        return pdfView
    }
    private func displayPdf(FileName:String) {
        let pdfView = self.createPdfView(withFrame: self.view.bounds)
        if let pdfDocument = self.createPdfDocument(forFileName: FileName) {
            self.view.addSubview(pdfView)
            pdfView.autoScales = true
            pdfView.document = pdfDocument
        }
    }
```

I tried to put a button inside the pdf file but it's not showing.

Comment: You need to have a nevigationController and push the pdfView or a view containing it.

Comment: How can I connect between PDFView and the storyboard? I have nevigationController already.